SVG becomes blurry after scaling with React Native Reanimated
I am working on a React Native project where I use React Native Reanimated to scale an SVG dynamically. My goal is to allow pinch-to-zoom and pan gestures on an SVG, but after scaling, the SVG becomes blurry.
Here is the relevant part of my code:
const animatedStyles = useAnimatedStyle(() => ({
  transform: [
    { translateX: translationX.value },
    { translateY: translationY.value },
    { scale: scale.value },
  ],
}));

const pinchGesture = Gesture.Pinch()
  .onStart((event) => {
    scaleValue.value = scale.value;
  })
  .onUpdate((event) => {
    const adjustedScale = 1 + (event.scale - 1) * PINCH_SENSITIVITY;
    scale.value = scaleValue.value * adjustedScale;
  });


I use the react-native-svg library to render the SVG and manage scaling using Reanimated. Here's the rendering part:
<GestureHandlerRootView style={{flex:1}}>
    <GestureDetector gesture={onGestureMain}>
    <Animated.View style={[animatedStyles,{flex:1, width:"100%", height:"100%"}]}>

    <Svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 290 500">
    <AnimatedCircle
    width={100}
    height={100}
    
        
          fill="#b58df1"
       
          // animatedProps={animatedProps}
        />
      {/* <Circle cx="145" cy="250" r="120" fill="#c02aaa"/> */}
    </Svg>


  </Animated.View>
  </GestureDetector>
  </GestureHandlerRootView>


